# ExtJS disable panel in FF + IE

Tags: extjs, panels

I have `Ext.getCmp("id").disable();` and it works in FF but not IE, if my panel id is test, or panel name is test, how would I disable it without doing disabled: true from the beginning?

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
Ext.getCmp('id').setDisabled(true);
```

setDisabled( Boolean disabled ) : Convenience function for setting disabled/enabled by boolean.

check [docs](http://extjs.cachefly.net/ext-3.2.0/docs/source/Component.html#method-Ext.Component-setDisabled)